# How to bring user to the exact same location after redirect?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-authentication

My registration page is scrollable and at the bottom the user will log in with `Google`, by being redirected to another page *and redirected back* .

When the user is redirected back to the page, it will load the top of the page, not the bottom.
I need to keep the state of that page (because the user might be redirected twice)

One way would be to scroll down when the redirect function happens. With Google it's:

```
firebase.auth().getRedirectResult().then(function(result) {here !}
```

Problem is, there is a delay of 2-3 seconds before this is returned.

How can I keep the state of a page **so *right* on page load, we go back to previous location** ?

Comment: You might try creating an element with an id like `<section id="redirect-to-me">` and have it redirect to `your-site.com/#redirect-to-me` to make it instantly scroll down

Comment: Yea I have this section ID, but how to do that when the page load ONLY after Google redirect? what function callback should I use/

Comment: Well, if the redirect is based on your current url, change the url before redirecting to google login. If it can be set up in Firebase you should do that.

Comment: Thanks, Firebase only go back to the same page, so I am not sure how to implement your other solution (change url before? how ? )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Change the URL to your `#element` to scroll instantly

You can have the page scroll instantly to the element you wish by changing the current URL before logging in.

Here is an example of changing the URL:

```js
// "Title" is currently ignored
history.pushState({}, "Title", "/your-url#id");
```

[MDN docs for travelling through `history`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API)